# Detect app url download location after iOS app install

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a requirement where i publish the iTunes app link to download the app in the website.

say i have 3 websites A, B, C
After the app is downloaded from the link, based on the website from where it has redirected i need to show custom message or image .

Say if the user click on download app on website A, then after the app is opened it should show "you have downloaded from website A"

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, simply because the user downloads the app from the App Store and not from the website.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with website development but I think you can set something on website where if you click on AppStore link it triggers an event to database and stores website name and whenever App is opened for the first time you call a web-service that interacts with your database and tells you the website name. ***But I do not think Apple will be happy seeing something like that in an App.***

Comment: And which type of record you would save on the DB when the user,from Safari, click on the iTunes link, to know that the user has clicked on that button? You can probably handle the headers in the request, in this case how you could add the headers values like userID or deviceID?

Comment: Like fire an insert query with website name, deviceID when user clicks on button on website. Not sure if you can track device ID on website or not. Or anything that would uniquely identify the device on website.